# Parsing a large (~40GB) XML text file in python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, large-files

I've got an XML file I want to parse with python. What is best way to do this? Taking into memory the entire document would be disastrous, I need to somehow read it a single node at a time.

Existing XML solutions I know of:

- element tree
- minixml

but I'm afraid they aren't quite going to work because of the problem I mentioned. Also I can't open it in a text editor - any good tips in generao for working with giant text files?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this file?  and how is it structured?

Comment: Are you familiar with SAX parsers?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan - it's a wikipedia dump. I want to do some graph analysis. whether that means I want to put it all in a SQL database first, I don't know.

Comment: @Gabe - no I'm not. what is the advantage of such parsers?

Comment: FWIW, opening it in a text editor should be easy. I use EmEditor, which works great by loading only parts of the file in memory. I'm sure there are other products that are just as good.

Comment: SAX is a standard XML parser interface for parsing a file as it's being read in, rather than a DOM interface that requires having the whole tihng in memory at once.

Comment: I am trying to do this using a Wikipedia dump also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, have you tried `ElementTree` (either the built-in pure-Python or C versions, or, better, the `lxml` version)? I'm pretty sure none of them actually read the whole file into memory.

The problem, of course, is that, whether or not it reads the whole file into memory, the resulting parsed tree ends up in memory.

ElementTree has a nifty solution that's pretty simple, and often sufficient: [iterparse](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm).

```
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(xmlfile, events=('end')):
  ...
```

The key here is that you can modify the tree as it's built up (by replacing the contents with a summary containing only what the parent node will need). By throwing out all the stuff you don't need to keep in memory as it comes in, you can stick to parsing things in the usual order without running out of memory.

The linked page gives more details, including some examples for modifying XML-RPC and plist as they're processed. (In those cases, it's to make the resulting object simpler to use, not to save memory, but they should be enough to get the idea across.)

This only helps if you can think of a way to summarize as you go. (In the most trivial case, where the parent doesn't need any info from its children, this is just `elem.clear()`.) Otherwise, this won't work for you.

The standard solution is [SAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML), which is a callback-based API that lets you operate on the tree a node at a time. You don't need to worry about truncating nodes as you do with iterparse, because the nodes don't exist after you've parsed them.

Most of the best SAX examples out there are for Java or Javascript, but they're not too hard to figure out. For example, if you look at http://cs.au.dk/~amoeller/XML/programming/saxexample.html you should be able to figure out how to write it in Python (as long as you know where to find [the documentation for xml.sax](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.html)).

There are also some DOM-based libraries that work without reading everything into memory, but there aren't any that I know of that I'd trust to handle a 40GB file with reasonable efficiency.

Comment: I ended up with cElementTree, which is super fast. Take a look at the benchmarks on the bottom of this page: http://effbot.org/zone/celementtree.htm, it beats most SAX parsers too (for python, anyway)

Comment: That's a bit of an old benchmark. Also, that's doing an in-memory string parse, not an iterparse. In my experience, cElementTree and lxml.etree are both almost always fast enough, and faster than anything else. lxml is more often faster, but not always. lxml isn't quite 100% compatible with ET in a few areas where cET is; most recently, I chose cET for a project because lxml's iterparse only lets you set `elem.data` to a string or None, and my summaries were ints, and the time lxml saved in parsing was less than the time wasted doing str and int… But anyway, glad you discovered that ER rocks.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution will depend in part on what you are trying to do, and how free your system resources are.  Converting it to a postgresql or similar database might not be a bad first goal; on the other hand, if you just need to pull data out once, it's probably not needed.  When I have to parse large XML files, especially when the goal is to process the data for graphs or the like, I usually convert the xml to S-expressions, and then use an S-expression interpreter (implemented in python) to analyse the tags in order and build the tabulated data.  Since it can read the file in a line at a time, the length of the file doesn't matter, so long as the resulting tabulated data all fits in memory.

Comment: S-expressions - kind of like pickling in python? is that actually a useful thing? never heard of it before, sound more like a theoretical niceity: http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Sexp.txt. For searching, grouping, etc it seems like mysql or postgre would be better?

Comment: It depends on how many times you need to parse the data. If you need to parse it multiple times, something like sqlite would be a better choice, because it gets the data into a compressed format and lets you run queries against it. s-exp is the syntax behind the lisp family of languages, which are nice in theory, but in practice lack a good common library. However, as a data structure, they are the same as xml, just easier to parse (no </> close tag syntax).  Basically, you execute the xml (kinda like ANT).  I've done it in the past as the way to get the xml loaded into a sqlite database.

Comment: P.S.  The best explanation of it I've found is here:  http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html  If there is any interest in the lisp interpreter I use, it's based off of lis.py, which you can find online, but has some extensions to integrate it into python code, I can make it available.